# How to use numpy where on each element of test array without a for-loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, where-clause

I would like to use a numpy function in a routine without using a for-loop. Consider the example below:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.linspace(1, 10, 10).astype(int) 
test_elements = np.array([1, 2])
for test_elem in test_elements:
    print(np.where(test_elem == data))
```

...

```
(array([0]),)
(array([1]),)
```

I've read other posts and the numpy documentation. Common suggestions seem to be using `np.roll` to roll `test_elements`, or using other tricks such as strides (which I do not completely understand). I thought it might be easier to use `np.vectorize` to vectorize the function, but I have a feeling that this is overkill for a problem and that there must be a simpler solution. Any guidance would be appreciated?

Comment: Hmm... Does your `data` have no duplicates? Otherwise the return values of `where` can be of different lengths (I guess even here it can have different lengths, as if a `test_elem` isn't there, the result would be empty), and numpy is not good at dealing with things of variable lengths.

Comment: In the example above, they are all unique. That's just because I was trying to make the problem simple. I planned to concatenate the unique elements at the end if there are duplicate entries.

Comment: The faster method will depend on the sizes of your actual data, and what you want to do with the results. Remember that the for loop is only really inefficient when the size of `data` is small (and the size of `test_elements` is large).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method using `.outer` and `np.split` I've made the example a bit more interesting.

```
data = np.linspace(1, 5, 10).astype(int) 
test_elements = np.array([1, 2, 4, 6])
y, x = np.where(np.equal.outer(test_elements,data))
np.split(x, y.searchsorted(np.arange(1,test_elements.size)))
# [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([7, 8]), array([], dtype=int64)]
```

Some explanation:

```
np.equal.outer(test_elements,data)
```

is the same as

```
 test.elements[:,None] == data[None,:]
```

So this is a 2d boolean array whose rows equal the boolean arrays `test_elem == data` occuring in your for loop.

`where` returns two index arrays from this, one for each coordinate. `x` is the fast changing coordinate and is equal to the values the 1d `where` of your for loop returns, but all glued together into one long vector. `y` is the slow chaning coordinate, it's values are ordered and can be used to group / split up `x`. `searchsorted` may not be the most efficient way of doing that but it is simple and handles empty rows correctly.

Comment: I see that this works. But you can explain a little of the logic? From my understanding, `.equal` is used to check ordered equality, the use of `.outer` is to broadcast these boolean values, and that `.searchsorted` is used to specify which values go into which bins (like in a histogram). But I don't fully understand how your solution works.

Comment: @allthemikeysaretaken added some explananations.